# How to correctly use MIBs for SNMP?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, mib

I'm currently trying to write a bash-monitoring-script for a Fujitsu Primergy RX300 S6, running with XenServer 6.5.0.
After downloading the MIB-files from the Fujitsu-Page I'm getting several errors, trying to run the following line `snmpget -Ov -v 2c -c PUBLICKEY SERVER.IP SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0`
I'm getting the correct result, but with that there are multiple errors like

> Unlinked OID in VMWARE-TRAPS-MIB: vmware ::= { enterprises 6876 }
>
> /usr/share/snmp/mibs/VMWARE-TRAPS-MIB.mib Textual convention doesn't map to real type (DisplayString): At line 26 in usr/share/snmp/mibs/log3v1.mib : (is a reserved word): At line 27 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/log3v1.mib : (is a reserved word): At line 28 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/log3v1.mib Unlinked OID in FSC-LOG3-MIB: sni ::= { enterprises 231 }
>
> Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 13 of
>
> [...]

I do unterstand, that it says that some definitions (from foreign MIBs) are missing, but how do I get the correct ones?

Comment: http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Beginners%27%20Guide%20on%20MIB%20Documents you will have to find the proper reference documents yourself or ask Fujitsu customer support for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **IMPORTS** definition in MIB files that you are trying to use. These are basically your external dependencies. Try downloading these MIB MODULEs either from vendor website or if it is standard MIB file like *RFC1155-SMI* and *RFC1213* you can easily find it via google.

Here is an example:

```
IMPORTS
   enterprises, OBJECT-TYPE
   FROM RFC1155-SMI
            DisplayString
                      FROM RFC1158-MIB;
```

Comment: Thank you, that one was the right tip. 
I removed all MIBs from the folder and reincluded the ones I really need. You saved my monday! :-)